# CodeIgniter 3 with IIS 7.5

Tags: php, codeigniter, iis-7.5

I spend some time to read several topics without success. So I ask the question again, even if that problem is already explained.
First  : I'm not a developper, so I have a small knowledge of PHP and I don't know CI.
I must insall a webapps using CI onto a server. This apps was developed under a WAMP stack
For corporate reasons I must install it onto a Windows 2008R2 / IIS 7.5 server.

The technical configuration is : 
OS : Windows 2008R2 64bits sp1
Web server : IIS 7.5 web server (version 7.5.7600.16385)
DB : MySQL 5.7.21
PHP : version 7.2.2 running as FastCGI
Mysqli extension is enabled.
CodeIgniter : 3.1.6

Webserver is located c:\inetpub\wwwroot (default windows / IIS configuraiton).
Into this web root folder I have a subFolder /ABC/ 
into this folder I have CI folder "/system" and "/application" folder.

in the session directory (/ABC/session/) CI_session*xyz* token are well generated.

When I try to access to my application I have a 404 error.

To complete the config I have :

**routes.php :**

```
$route['default_controller'] = 'Admin';
$route['404_override'] = '404 Page Not Found';
$route['translate_uri_dashes'] = FALSE;
```

---

**Admin.php** is my controller and located in 
/ABC/application/controllers/ folder.

---

in **URI.php** I added in function _parse_request_uri()

```
if(!isset($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']))
        $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
```

---

In the root folder I have a.htaccess file with this values :

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ./index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

(I tried others values found into stoackoverflow forum without success)

---

In the **config.php** file I have :

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://rexbiz-nxt11pro/ABC';
```

in **index.php** located into root folder (ie c:\inetpub\wwwroot\ABC) I have :

```
$system_path = 'system';
$application_folder = 'application';
$view_folder = '';
```

With all thoses setting I have a http 404 error.
If I change index.php with values like this (slash added) :

```
$system_path = '/system';
$application_folder = '/application';
$view_folder = '';
```

I haven't got 404 error enymore, but : 
"Your system folder path does not appear to be set correctly. Please open the following file and correct this: index.php"

I don't know if the porblem commes from relative path (sometimes with windows there is issues with / or ) or from somewhere else.

Thank's for your help

Answer (score 1):

IIS does not do anything with `.htaccess` files.

You will have to either:

[Convert the `.htaccess` code into something which IIS can understand.](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/azureossds/2015/04/23/converting-apache-htaccess-rules-to-iis-web-config-using-iis-manager-for-azure-websites/)

or

Disable IIS and install/configure/run an Apache HTTPD server.