# Error 403 Forbbiden access switching from local to live server (windows)

Tags: .htaccess, codeigniter, http-status-code-403

i made a small website and everythign works on local, but now im switching to live server and im getting a 403 forbbiden access. Im using codeigniter and the live server is windows. Im suing a file manager from the provider and i have the files in the current path: mywebsite.pt > htdocs > www > myapp
[MY folders](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ah6o8.png)
My full .htaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
# !IMPORTANT! Set your RewriteBase here and don't forget trailing and leading
# slashes.
# If your page resides at
# http://www.example.com/mypage/test1
# then use
# RewriteBase /mypage/test1/
RewriteBase /Front/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
# If we don't have mod_rewrite installed, all 404's
# can be sent to index.php, and everything works as normal.
# Submitted by: ElliotHaughin
ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
```

My Config file:

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://meusite.pt/';
$config['index_page'] = '';
```

Comment: please explain how the live server is running: is it IIS or apache on a windows machine?

Comment: i think it might be IIS because there is a IIS settings there

Comment: well, but IIS doesn't use .htaccess, it uses web.config, see here https://stackoverflow.com/a/48768238/2275490 or here https://forum.codeigniter.com/thread-65798.html

Answer (score 0):

Since it was my first time putting a website on a windows server i didnt even remember i needed to configure the server to PHP and not .NET. Just went in the server configurations and set it to PHP and not .NET. All done.